# Proving that for a free subset of a vectorspace V with m elements, any subset of V with less than m elements doesn't span V

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm having some trouble proving that given the vectorspace (ℝ,V,+) and A = {$x_1, x_2, ... , x_m$} a subset of $m$ vectors of $V$, if $A$ is linearly independent, then every subset of $V$ with less than $m$ vectors does not span $V$.

My idea was using a contradiction, taking a free subset $B$ and saying that you can write the vectors in $A$ as a linear combination of the vectors in $B$, which should lead to a contradiction, but I don't know if what I'm doing is justified. This is what I have so far:

Let $B$ be a subset of $V$ with $n<m$ linearly independent vectors {$y_1, ... ,y_n$}, and write the vectors in $A$ as a linear combination of the vectors $y_i$

\begin{cases}
    x_1 = a_{11}y_1 + ... + a_{1n}y_n\\
    ...\\...\\ x_m = a_{m1}y_1 + ... + a_{mn}y_n\\
\end{cases}

This is a system with $m$ equations and $n$ parameters. As $m>n$, this system is overdetermined. For this system to have a solution at least one equation must be a linear combination of the other equations in the system.$^1$ This implies that there are two possible situations for the system:

1. No equations are linear combinations of others, making the system inconsistent. This means that the vectors in $A$ cannot be written as a linear combination of the vectors in $B$, meaning that B does not span $V$
2. At least one equations is a linear combination of the others, implying that the subset $A$ is not free, which contradicts our assumption, Therefore $B$ cannot span $V$

In both cases $B$ cannot span $V$, so we have proven the assumption

My doubt starts at $^1$ as I'm not sure if from here on out this is enough to prove the assumption, i.e. if I am allowed to use that in this proof.
Thanks for any help and I am translating this proof from a different language, so apologies for any mistakes in grammar/wrong words to use in proof, the original sounds better, it's really just the mathematical justification I need advice on.

Comment: What you did looks correct, but too complicated. If $B\subsetneq A$, there is some $x_i\in A\setminus B$. If $B$ spans $V$, then $x_i=\sum \lambda_jx_j$ for some $\lambda_j\in\mathbb R$ where the sum runs over the elements of $B$. It follows that $0=x_i-\sum\lambda_jx_j$ is a nontrivial linear combination of $0$, contradicting the linear independence of $A$.